# Why template is not compiling in tests?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I wrote a [spec for my controller](https://github.com/PavelDemyanenko/ng-countdown-ribbon/blob/58f83a1a25de67edce7d0e01a0f0d254811a9d30/tests/ng-countdown-ribbon.spec.js).
Angular module ngCountdownRibbon has a logic that adds a ribbon with counter to document body. In getRibbonDate function I want to access this computed values and check them in test (innerText of html element). But somehow it's not compiled when I try to get it. How I can get this spec working?

**The desired behavior**

Compiled code appended in document body should be:

```
  <a ng-href="http://amzn.com/w/ZWFNUL8AGNLP" class="ribbon-container ng-scope" 
     target="_blank" href="http://amzn.com/w/ZWFNUL8AGNLP">
    <span class="ribbon ribbon_left" ng-class="ngCountdownRibbon.ribbonClass"> 
      <span>
        <ng-pluralize
            count="ngCountdownRibbon.ribbonDays"
            when="{'0': 'Event has come', 'one': '1 day left', 'other': '{} days left'}"
            <="" 
            ng-pluralize="">1 day left
        </ng-pluralize>
      </span>
    </span>
  </a>
```

**What I get in compiled code now**

```
LOG:
 <a ng-href="{{ngCountdownRibbon.ribbonLink}}" class="ribbon-container ng-scope" 
       target="_blank">
    <span class="ribbon" ng-class="ngCountdownRibbon.ribbonClass">
      <span>
        <ng-pluralize
          count="ngCountdownRibbon.ribbonDays"
          when="{'0': 'Event has come', 'one': '1 day left', 'other': '{} days left'}"
          <="" ng-pluralize="">
        </ng-pluralize>
      </span>
    </span>
</a>
```

The shortest way to reproduce is to fork [repo](https://github.com/PavelDemyanenko/ng-countdown-ribbon) and run 'npm test' command from branch init-tests

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to **reproduce it in the question itself.**

Comment: Yeah, sure. I'll edit this question in a minute

Comment: @georgeawg done :)

Comment: @georgeawg but it works though, these attributes are only seen when I edit html code from inspector (to copy it her). Rendered version can be seen here http://paveldemyanenko.github.io/ng-countdown-ribbon, as you can see no illegal characters in inspector. Only when you edit you see these illegal characters. I don't know why it works like that in browser